# Why was my comment simply thanking a commenter and quoting a definition deleted as not being nice?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

After posting [Can passengers flying into Thailand do the mandatory 14-day quarantine at home?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157053/1810),  someone commented "is this even relevant for "travel"?", to which I replied ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504133054/https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157053/can-passengers-flying-into-thailand-do-the-mandatory-14-day-quarantine-at-home)):

> thanks, travel = "make a journey, typically of some length or abroad." https://google.com/search?q=travel+definition

My comment got deleted by a mod, the reason being ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200504143449/https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157053/can-passengers-flying-into-thailand-do-the-mandatory-14-day-quarantine-at-home)):

> remember, Be nice. The doubt whether this fit is real, not every bit of travel knowledge fits this site."

Why was my comment simply thanking a commenter and quoting a definition deleted as not being nice?

Comment: Answered under the question, as you deleted your first meta question while I answered it.

Comment: @Willeke sorry for the deletion, this is due to a Stack Exchange bug which caused the question being posted twice (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4oXX.png). could you please move the comment here? Thanks!

Comment: No, I have answered, you have seen it. I am not a secretary who has nothing to do than posting replies.

Comment: @Willeke ok happy to do it myself.

Comment: This is not worth to have a Meta discussion in my view, many people post comments, many people flag comments, many comments get deleted. Many people get warned that their tone of voice in the comments is taken as unfriendly. I am not going to close or delete this question, as you feel it is worth posting. But I am not going to act further on this (and do not accept you posting my comment as an answer.)

Comment: @Willeke thanks for your feedback,  hopefully the two flaggers or others can give their input.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't see your original comment, but yes, giving a definition of the word travel seems a bit ridiculous. We use a restricted definition of "travel" here anyway. A reply comment that states that you think your question fits the criteria for Travel SE might have been more appropriate.

Your question asked about quarantining at "home", if that's the case, it sounds more like an expats question. A case could be made that the quarantining is required because of travel outside Thailand and thus the question is valid for the Travel stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I copied my comment in the question above. The comment was simply "thanks, travel = "make a journey, typically of some length or abroad." https://google.com/search?q=travel+definition"

Comment: I disagree with the notion that travel done by expats isn't travel and ought to be off-topic here. However, there is nothing in this question that suggest it's specifically about expats. What about a Thai citizen who got stranded on holiday? The only restricted definition of travel that excludes this question is one that restricts travel to travel-as-done-by-Europeans (and North Americans) where Thailand is a “destination” and only interesting inasmuch as it is open to Europeans for fun.